# Checking for Dictionary key from Razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app that I've inherited. The app uses a `Dictionary<string, string>` for `Translations`. That `Dictionary` is stored on the `Application` object. Currently, I have the following:

```
@foreach (var key in Model.MyDictionary.Keys)
{
  var definition = Model.MyDictionary[key];
  ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
  viewData["key"] = key;
  viewData["value"] = ((Dictionary<string, string>)(HttpContext.Current.Application["Translations"]))[key];
  Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_Definition.cshtml", definition, viewData);
}
```

This approach works except if the `key` is not found in `Translations`. How can I elegantly ensure that the key exists in the `Translations` dictionary from my Razor code? I can't seem to identify a good way to do this.

Thank you for your help and happy holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if the key exists in the `Dictionary`.

```
@{
   var translations = ((Dictionary<string, string>)(HttpContext.Current.Application["Translations"]));
}
@foreach (var key in Model.MyDictionary.Keys)
{
  var definition = Model.MyDictionary[key];
  ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
  viewData["key"] = key;
  viewData["value"] = translations.ContainsKey(key) ? translations[key] : string.Empty;
  Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_Definition.cshtml", definition, viewData);
}
```

I'm not a fun of doing any calculations in the view, but this should work. If the key doesn't exist an empty string will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `Dictionary` which returns a `bool` indicating whether a key exists in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
@if (Dictionary.ContainsKey("SomeKey") == true)
{
    //"SomeKey" present
}
else
{
    //"SomeKey" not present
}
```

There are several ways to iterate through a `Dictionary`,  here is one iterating through each `KeyValuePair`:

```
@foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in Model.MyDictionary)
{
    //entry.Key with it's corresponding entry.Value can now be used in your code
    viewData["key"] = entry.Key;
    viewData["value"] = //check if Translations.ContainsKey(entry.Key) here
}
```